# How do you add existing objects to a ManyToMany field using Serializer?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an API with Artists and Songs, with a ManyToMany relationship between the two. Using the API to create a Song with an Artist that is not in the database works fine. The problem arises when I attempt to use the `POST` method to create a new Song with an Artist that already exists in the database. I tried overwriting the SongSerializer `create()` method using `get_or_create()` based on another post here, but I kept getting Bad Request errors when the Artist already exists in the database. The relevant code snippets:

models.py

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['artist_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.artist_name

class Song(models.Model):
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist, related_name='songs')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['song_title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

serializers.py

```
class ArtistNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = ('artist_name',)

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.artist_name

class SongTitleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    songs = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, many=True)

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.song_title

    class Meta:
        model = Song
        fields = ('songs',)

class ArtistSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    songs = SongTitleSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = ('id', 'artist_name', 'songs')

class SongSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    artists = ArtistNameSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Song
        fields = ('id', 'song_title', 'artists',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        artist_data = validated_data.pop('artists')
        song = Song.objects.create(**validated_data)
        song.save()
        for artist_item in artist_data:
            a, created = Artist.objects.get_or_create(artist_name=artist_item['artist_name'])
            song.artists.add(a)
        return song
```

I've done some tests and it looks like the program doesn't even go into the `create()` method I'm using, going straight to showing me the Bad Request error. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On you Artist model you have a constrain on the artist_model field (unique=True)

if you print the serializer in question with:

```
print(SongSerializer())
```

you get something like this:

```
SongSerializer():
id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
song_title = CharField(max_length=200)
artists = ArtistNameSerializer(many=True):
artist_name = CharField(max_length=200, validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=Artist.objects.all())>])
```

under the artist_name field is a Validator "UniqueValidator"

so in case of a write operation you can disable the validator in the serializer with:

```
class ArtistNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = models.Artist
    fields = ('artist_name',)
    extra_kwargs = {
        'artist_name': {
            'validators': [],
        }
    }
```

hope this help..

Comment: Fantastic! That worked out exactly like I wanted it to, thanks!